# How to send notifications when app was closed

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating an android app that consists of android push notifications.Here i need the push notifications that will run even when the app was closed. I had achieved it by calling the notification in a service. But here when i was running the code in the android >5.x devices my code was running perfectly even when app was closed notification was coming for every 5 sec but when i was running app on devices <5.x notifications was displaying only when the app was opened or when it was minimised not receiving any notifications when app was closed can any one help me what my mistake is and this is my code

SERVICE:

```
package com.example.servicesandroid;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.example.servicesandroid.MainActivity.MyTimerTask;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Androidservice extends Service {

    final static String ACTION = "NotifyServiceAction";
    final static String STOP_SERVICE = "";
    final static int RQS_STOP_SERVICE = 1;

    NotifyServiceReceiver notifyServiceReceiver;

    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification myNotification;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timer_task;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        notifyServiceReceiver = new NotifyServiceReceiver();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();

        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 5000, 1500);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return  Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.unregisterReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class NotifyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int rqs = arg1.getIntExtra("RQS", 0);
            if (rqs == RQS_STOP_SERVICE) {
                stopSelf();


            }
        }
    }
    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {

            generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "Hello");
        }
    }
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        Notification notification;
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        // To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
        // "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
                    contentIntent);
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context);
            notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                    .setContentText(message).build();

            notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

        }

    }

}
```

This is my activity:

```
package com.example.servicesandroid;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Androidservice.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

This is my Broadcast receiver when device reboots:

```
package com.example.servicesandroid;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Boot_Completed extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION)){
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Androidservice.class);
               context.startService(myIntent);

    }

}

}
```

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servicesandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".Androidservice"/>
        <receiver android:name=".Boot_Completed" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please any one help me with this

Comment: you need to check whether your app is active or not [Checkout this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152268/android-gcm-notification-builder-features-not-working-when-app-is-closed/36152406#36152406)

Comment: might be like your service getting killed because of lack of resources when ur app is closed.

Comment: When i am closing my application i had seen my application in settings->apps->i am having my application with 0 process and 1 service.But the same app seeing on 5.x devices those are showing with result of 1 process and 1 service even app was closed fully

Comment: I also tried for same functionality like registering to the server for every minute. I tried like you writing timer task and scheduling. Failed to achieve that functionality. Some times service was getting killed. After lollipop version os kills if service is idle. plz let me know if you find any sollution.

Comment: I tried fore ground service tooo

Comment: Can you explain me in detail @PrashanthDebbadwar